# Manipulating ComboBoxes in wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, combobox, wxpython

I'm using Python and wxPython to create an UI that lets the user select a XML file in the first combobox and all the components (i.e. buttons) in the XML appears as choices of another combobox below. It's clearly reading correctly as it prints out the right thing in the console as I go through all the XMLs, but I just can't seem to link it back to the combobox I'm looking for.

Here's the code:

```
import wx
import os
import xml.dom.minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import parse


# get all xmls
path = "C:\Users\William\Desktop\RES\Param"
files = os.listdir(path)

class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.xmlList = files
        self.xmlPickerTitle = wx.StaticText(self, label="XML Picker", pos=(20, 30))
        self.xmlPicker = wx.ComboBox(self, pos=(100, 30), size=(500, -1), choices=self.xmlList, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)

        self.elementsTitle = wx.StaticText(self, label="Elements Found", pos=(20, 100))
        # labels
        self.buttonsPickerTitle = wx.StaticText(self, pos=(20,120), label="Buttons")

        self.buttonList = []

        self.buttonsPicker = wx.ComboBox(self, pos=(100, 120), size=(250, -1), choices=buttonList, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.XMLSelect,)


    def XMLSelect(self, event):
        xmlPicked = self.xmlList[event.GetSelection()]
        DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse(xmlPicked)
        collection = DOMTree.documentElement

        buttons = DOMTree.getElementsByTagName("Button")

        for button in buttons:
            if button.hasAttribute("name"):
                buttonList.append(button.getAttribute("name"))
                print button.getAttribute("name")
app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, title = "Auto", size = (800, 600))
panel = Panel(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post a sample of one of your xml files

Comment: Just did, please check it out and see if you can help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an issue with the file name not containing the path so I have had to join them to pass into xmlPicked but that might be a difference between linux and Windows.
The key point is to `Clear()` and `Append()` to the `ComboBox`
Also, `Bind` to a specific `ComboBox` because you have 2.
Finally, set the selection for the `ComboBox` so that it is obvious that you have data available.

```
import wx
import os
import xml.dom.minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import parse


# get all xmls
path = "/home/whatever"
files = os.listdir(path)

class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.xmlList = files
        self.xmlPickerTitle = wx.StaticText(self, label="XML Picker", pos=(20, 30))
        self.xmlPicker = wx.ComboBox(self, pos=(100, 30), size=(500, -1), choices=self.xmlList, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)

        self.elementsTitle = wx.StaticText(self, label="Elements Found", pos=(20, 100))
        # labels
        self.buttonsPickerTitle = wx.StaticText(self, pos=(20,120), label="Buttons")

        self.buttonList = []

        self.buttonsPicker = wx.ComboBox(self, pos=(100, 120), size=(250, -1), choices=self.buttonList, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)

        self.xmlPicker.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.XMLSelect,)



    def XMLSelect(self, event):
        self.buttonsPicker.Clear()
        xmlPicked = self.xmlList[event.GetSelection()]
        xmlPicked = os.path.join(path,xmlPicked)
        DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse(xmlPicked)
        collection = DOMTree.documentElement
        buttons = DOMTree.getElementsByTagName("Button")
        for button in buttons:
            if button.hasAttribute("name"):
                button_name = str(button.getAttribute("name"))
                self.buttonsPicker.Append(button_name)
                print button_name
        self.buttonsPicker.SetSelection(0)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, title = "Auto", size = (800, 600))
panel = Panel(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I too had the problem of not being able parse the file without a directory, I found it out myself later after the post here. Otherwise, your code worked perfectly for my need, thanks!